# Setting value to checkboxes in a form

Tags: forms

I've been having troubles with form_set_value(). I've extended the Search form, everything works, but after submission, the form values for those fields added by me return to default (see the code).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
<?
/**
 * implementation of function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 */
function myModule_form_search_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){

    $form['myM_options']['entity'] = array(
                                            '#type' => 'radios',
                                            '#title' => 'Search by',
                                            '#default_value' => 'gene',
                                            '#options' => array(
                                                                "gene" => "Genes",
                                                                "ortholog" => "Orthologs",
                                                                "microarray" => "Microarray Features"
                                                            ),

                                        );
    $form['myM_options']['plant'] = array(
                                            '#type' => 'checkboxes',
                                            '#title' => 'Choose plants',
                                            '#options' => formatPlants(),
                                            // select all checkboxes by default
                                            '#default_value' => array_keys(formatPlants()),
                                        );
    $form['#validate'][] = 'myModule_search_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'myModule_search_form_alter_submit';
}
/**
 * validation functoin
 */
function myModule_search_validate( $form, &$form_state ){
    // this works as expected
    form_set_value($form['basic']['processed_keys'], trim($form_state['values']['keys']), $form_state);

    // this doesn't !!!
    form_set_value($form['myM_options']['entity'], $form_state['values']['entity'], $form_state);
    form_set_value($form['myM_options']['plant'], array( 'id_1', 'id_2' ), $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **$form**: An associative array containing the structure of the form,
>   which is ***passed by reference***. Form validation handlers are able to
>   alter the form structure (like #process and #after_build callbacks
>   during form building) in case of a validation error. If a validation
>   handler alters the form structure, it is responsible for validating
>   the values of changed form elements in $form_state['values'] to
>   prevent form submit handlers from receiving unvalidated values.

So your form validation function should be as the following:

```
/**
 * validation functoin
 */
function myModule_search_validate( &$form, &$form_state ) {
  // function body
}
```

Then in your form submit function you need to set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` as following:

```
/**
 * submit functoin
 */
function plant_Ontlogy_search_form_alter_submit( &$form, &$form_state ) {
  // function body

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

If setting state rebuild to TRUE didn't work with you by itself, try to set default value as the following example to each additional field:

```
$form['myM_options']['entity'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Search by',
  '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['entity'])? $form_state['values']['entity'] : 'gene',
  '#default_value' => 'gene',
  '#options' => array(
    "gene" => "Genes",
    "ortholog" => "Orthologs",
    "microarray" => "Microarray Features"
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this didn't work.
The values selected pass into the hook_search_exec() as expected. The form, after being rebuild for the results page returns to default values, not the values selected by the user.

Comment: @Fuzzy I edited my answer with additional solution for your issue.